# Stop Django server without control key

Tags: django, linux

I need to kill the Django development server from a shellscript in linux. How can this be done, since the shell script can't hold the 'CONTROL' key? Is there sytnax that performs the same function? 
I tried:

```
$CONTROL-C
$^C
$SIGINT
```

Comment: You need to find which process is the django development server and kill that process. `ps -aux` shows you the processes, `kill xxxx` kills the process number xxxx.

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kill` to kill the process that is running your Django server:

- `ps -ax` shows you all the running processes, you could `ps -ax | grep runserver` to just show the processes with `runserver` in them
- `kill xxxx` kills the process number xxxx